# Infinte Series with Conditions

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if someone could give me a hint about how to get started on this problem, and/or hide the solution to it. I really want to try it on my own first.

Suppose $a_k \geq 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum a_k < \infty$. Either prove that the given series converges, or give an example for which it diverges:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{a_k}k}$.

Comment: Hint: What are some ways to use the convergence of one series to prove the convergence of another? (What tests do you know that work like this?)

Comment: I seem to have misread the question. I apologize if my comment misled you. Brian's answer should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT $1$: Look for a counterexample.

If $b_k=\sqrt{a_k/k}$, you want $\sum_kb_k$ to diverge while $\sum_ka_k=\sum_kkb_k^2$ converges, so $\langle kb_k:k\ge 1\rangle$ has to converge to $0$ faster than $\langle b_k:k\ge 1\rangle$. It’s a good bet that $\sum_ka_k$ will be just barely convergent, while $\sum_kb_k$ will just barely diverge. The most obvious ‘barely divergent’ series is the harmonic series, but it’s not good enough: you’ll need $\sum_kb_k$ to diverge even slower than the harmonic series.

HINT $2$:

> Try $b_k=\dfrac1{kf(k)}$ for some slowly growing function $f$, so that $a_k=\dfrac1{k(f(k))^2}$.

HINT $3$:

> What is $\displaystyle\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x(\ln x)^2}$? Does this give you any ideas for $a_k$?

There may well be other nice solutions; this was the first that occurred to me.

Comment: Thank! I will give this a shot!

Comment: @phatty: You’re welcome! Even the third hint doesn’t actually complete the solution, so if you get completely stuck, don’t hesitate to leave me a question.

Comment: Thanks, I got it! Is there a "cleaner" method that you can think of?

Comment: @phatty: Excellent! I couldn’t come up with any really systematic approach when I was thinking about it; I just nibbled around the edges, so to speak, thinking along the general lines of my first paragraph up there, and the idea of using logs pretty quickly led to the example.